# Enrutamiento en ANGULAR 5

Tags: html, web, angular, typescript

espero que me puedas ayudar con lo siguiente:

tengo el siguiente código:

```
this._router.navigate(['./admin']);
```

Me gustaría saber si existe la posibilidad de navegar hasta esa ruta mediante el comportamiento del atributo **href**, es decir, que recargue completamente la aplicación.

Cualquier sugerencia es bienvenida. Gracias.

Comment: ¿Lo has probado?

Comment: no reinicia los componentes si es la pregunta, tendrías que inyectar un servicio y/o subscribirte a los eventos del router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres que refresque el url, puedes hacerlo de varias formas.
Window.Location por ejemplo

```
window.location.assign("https://www.google.com")
```

Obviamente en lugar de google... escribes tu ruta